# android: draw outside of closed path instead of inside

Tags: android, drawing

I am drawing a filled polygon on a canvas in android.

```
canvas.drawPath(path,myPaint);
```

Now I want to do exactly the opposite: Fill the area outside of the polygon.

how can I tell the paint to fill the outer region - the region which is not covered by the polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be complicated or very simple.

The complicated way:

Create a path exactly like your polygon, except don't close it. The continue that path to the nearest wall. Draw around the walls. Close and fill. In code, this isn't too fun.

The simple way:

Color the canvas. Draw the polygon.

Good luck.

Answer (score 11):

simply use

```
path.setFillType(FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);
```

Comment: is it working, may i have sample here. Thanks in advance